# Capture Site URL in APEX

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, custom-domain

we have a functionality where users get an email with a link to a Salesforce site (that hosts a VF Page). Once they click on the link in the email it takes that that that site. 
But I am struggling to generate a string that will dynamically generate URL in my class.

I am working in a scratch org and created a Domain and Site; my final URL looks like this for the site: **https://sandbox-xyzwys.cs68.force.com**

But Prod already has domain activated and other sites created (so does full sandbox). So when I migrate work to full sandbox and Prod my site migrates over, but its URL changes:  **https://dev-ABCDZ.cs70.force.com**

If I query Domain `SELECT Domain,DomainType,Id FROM Domain` it returns nothing in my scratch org and does return completely different Domain in the sandbox: **https://dev-QAZXSW.cs70.force.com**

Please help me generate a string that will dynamically crate a valid URL that can be referenced in APEX and can be easily migrated between the orgs.

Comment: I have no idea if this works (that's why this is not an answer), but I found it online and thought I would pass it along. https://wedgecommerce.com/how-to-get-site-url-salesforce/